# How do I parse url after searching?

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization

I'm trying to parse a specifc part of url after search using
any language.(Ideally Javascript but open to Python)

How do I get a specific part of url and save/store?

For example,
In songking.com,
The way to get artist_id is checking a specific part of the url after searching artist name
in the search bar of the website.

in the case below, 
the artist id is **301329**.

https://www.songkick.com/artists/**301329**-rac

I strongly believe there is a way to parse this part using either python or js
given that I have a csv file that has artist name in its column. Instead of searching all the artists one by one. I wonder about the algorithm that literate my csv column and search it and parse the url and save/store.

[image]

It would be very grateful even if I could only get a hint that I could start with.

Thank you so much always.

Comment: Are all URLs formatted like this? `id-rac`

Comment: @NoSkillMan Yes all the url has the same format 'rac'is artist name. So url format is 'atist-id'-'artistname'

Comment: their API includes artist searching with results returned in json/xml format. I would suggest it is likely cleaner than parsing URL's.  https://www.songkick.com/developer/artist-search. Feel free to come back with questions on the API if you like.

Comment: @RonanHughes Thank you soooooooo much!!!! If you don't mind, can I ask you one more? I wonder how I iterate through the artist column and get the 'artist_id' that is 'exact match' as the artist name?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using regular expressions.

Here's an example of a JavaScript implementation

```js
const url = "https://www.songkick.com/artists/301329-rac";

const regex = /https:\/\/www\.songkick\.com\/artists\/(\d+)-.+/;

const match = url.match(regex);

if (match) {
  console.log('Artist ID: ' + match[1]);
} else {
  console.log('No Artist ID found!');
}
```

This regular expression `/https:\/\/www\.songkick\.com\/artists\/(\d+)-.+/` means that we're trying to match something that starts with https://www.songkick.com/artists/, preceded by a group of decimals a dash then a group of letters.

> The match() method retrieves the result of matching a string against a
>   regular expression.

Thus it will return the overall string in the first index, then the matched `(\d+)` group in the second index (`match[1]` in our case).

If you're not sure of the protocol (http vs https) you can add a `?` in the regex right after https. That makes the s in https optional. So the regex would become `/https?:\/\/www\.songkick\.com\/artists\/(\d+)-.+/`.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is I need to get artist id first based on the artists name that I have in my csv file. and to get the artist-id, I need to feed artist name string into the following url.
https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?apikey={your_api_key}&query={artist_name}.
How do I make js to read artist name in my csv file and feed the string into the url and parse the id in the json file

Comment: You can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse to parse your CSV file and get your artist_name

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use **RegEx** simply.
In `python`

```
import re
url = 'https://www.songkick.com/artists/301329-rac'
pattern = '/artists/(\d+)-\w'
match = re.search(pattern, url)
if match:
    artist_id = match.group(1)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you. How does python search something for me after reading the data that I have in csv? Regex is just a pattern to read the url format. I hope to get an algorithm that execute 'searching' on behalf of me.

Comment: In your pattern, you do not need to escape the `/` - you are probably thinking of languages where `/`...`/` is used to delimit the regex. Also the `-` would only need possible escaping inside a character class.